# How to Use Microsoft XAML Border on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to know what would be a XAML windows phone "Border" to Xamarin Forms? there's no Border to use BorderThickness, i want to draw some "lines" and set inside of 5 row's.Thanks

XAML Windows Phone :

`<Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="#fe98fe"/>`

I found a `Frame` on xamarin it does almost the same thing as `Border` but is not looking good for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to draw a Line, you can use the `BoxView` https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BoxView/

Example for a horizontal line with height 2:

```
<BoxView Color="Red" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
```

But there is currently no feature complete counterpart for `Border`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="End"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></BoxView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I did use `BoxView` but when i put inside of my `RowDefinition` i got a large Rectangle [here](http://i.imgur.com/1Fmv4TU.png)

Comment: Have you set `HeightRequest="2"`? If yes: how does your XAML look?

Comment: I found the solution doing this `<BoxView Color="Red"
                 HeightRequest="2"
                 WidthRequest="1"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Rotation="-90"
                 HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>`
but, when i use inside of RowDefinition became small! can we chat?

Comment: That's my Row `<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>`

Comment: Use `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>` or `<RowDefinition Height="2"/>` for the rows with the lines.

Comment: didn't work, i use `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` becase the five lines has to be the same distance

Comment: Ahh ok. then you have to set `VerticalOptions` see my updated answer for the example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108727/discussion-between-nathiel-paulino-and-sven-michael-stube).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do the same way as the accepted answer suggest.

The best thing to do (IMHO) is either to use a Frame or a Grid/StackLayout/AnyContainerHere.

Here is what I would do

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="YourBorderColorHere" Padding="YourBorderWidthValueWhichIsNotOfTypeThickness">
    <YourContentHere [BackgroundColor="YourInnerBackgroundHere"]/>        
    <!-- If you don't have a content to set, use a BoxView with a different color (your background color)-->
</Grid>
```

This would do the same with less control, less rendering stuff so better perf.
If you want corner radius do the same thing with a Frame.

If the author didn't like the Frame appearance, he should had try to set on its Frame a CornerRadius to 0 and HasShadow to False.

The less control and content to render, the better !
I like to quote Van der Rohe : "Less is more"

If you just want to draw a Line (Border with Thickness = 0,0,0,2), use a BoxView.

Comment: Kind of a shame that there's no support for <Border/> control. That's such a basic element.

Comment: @NickeManarin the Border almost == the Frame (which is an advanced border). But you are right, they should provide a lighter control to add border to any control such a Label or anything else.